# file_get_contents does not send data content in a POST request

Tags: php, arduino

I am attempting to send a POST request to an arduino from a PHP script that is called by a web page. I am using file_get_contents() to accomplish this. I have read the examples from the PHP manual here: [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). It appears that the Arduino is receiving the POST request but there is no content included in the data stream, only headers and content parameters. Here is my relevant php

```
        // send database updates to the arduino
        $url = 'http://'.$ip;
        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www/form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($responseText)
            ),
        );
        
        $context = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

currently on the Arduino I am just dumping the entire POST request to the terminal so that I can verify that it is being received. Here is the output of the Arduino terminal.

```
Ethernet WebServer Example
server is at 192.168.3.3
new client
POST / HTTP/1.0
Host: 192.168.3.3
Connection: close
Content-Length: 80
Content-type: application/x-www/form-urlencoded

client disconnected
```

As you can see the entire POST request is there accept the content. It shows the Content-Length but no actual content.

Here is the Arduino code that produced the terminal output. It is nothing more than the Web Server example that comes with the Arduino IDE.

```
/*
  Web Server

 A simple web server that shows the value of the analog input pins.
 using an Arduino Wiznet Ethernet shield.

 Circuit:
 * Ethernet shield attached to pins 10, 11, 12, 13
 * Analog inputs attached to pins A0 through A5 (optional)

 created 18 Dec 2009
 by David A. Mellis
 modified 9 Apr 2012
 by Tom Igoe
 modified 02 Sept 2015
 by Arturo Guadalupi
 
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 3, 3);

// Initialize the Ethernet server library
// with the IP address and port you want to use
// (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetServer server(80);

String postData;

void setup() {
  // You can use Ethernet.init(pin) to configure the CS pin
  Ethernet.init(10);  // Most Arduino shields
  //Ethernet.init(5);   // MKR ETH shield
  //Ethernet.init(0);   // Teensy 2.0
  //Ethernet.init(20);  // Teensy++ 2.0
  //Ethernet.init(15);  // ESP8266 with Adafruit Featherwing Ethernet
  //Ethernet.init(33);  // ESP32 with Adafruit Featherwing Ethernet

  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Serial.println("Ethernet WebServer Example");

  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  // Check for Ethernet hardware present
  if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
    while (true) {
      delay(1); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
    }
  }
  if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
  }

  // start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}


void loop() {
  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("new client");
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        //postData = postData + c;
        Serial.write(c);
        // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
        // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
        // so you can send a reply
        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
          // send a standard http response header
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
          //client.println("Refresh: 5");  // refresh the page automatically every 5 sec
          client.println();
          /*client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
          client.println("<html>");
          // output the value of each analog input pin
          for (int analogChannel = 0; analogChannel < 6; analogChannel++) {
            int sensorReading = analogRead(analogChannel);
            client.print("analog input ");
            client.print(analogChannel);
            client.print(" is ");
            client.print(sensorReading);
            client.println("<br />");
          }
          client.println("</html>");*/
          break;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        } else if (c != '\r') {
          // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);
    Serial.println("client disconnected");
  }
}
```

What is causing the content of the POST request to not be sent from the PHP?

Comment: why not curl? its easy and works better

Comment: Does this answer your question? [POST data to a URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080146/post-data-to-a-url-in-php)

Comment: @flakerimi I attempted cURL first but didn't get this far. I will try again with the example in the post that you linked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents ( you may try fopen -- near the end of this post )

Comment: `var_dump(http_build_query($responseText))` gives the intended string back? Also I dont see the `Content-Length` header here, is this a more minimal version?

Comment: @user3783243 yes, it does

Comment: @flakerimi When I use the curl example in the post you linked I get a "Call to undefined function curl_init()" error. Is there something that needs to be uncommented in php.ini to make this work?

Comment: @user3783243 is the Content-Length header not the 7th line in the Terminal output in the Original Post?

Comment: @kenLee I saw that post but was not able to get a workable answer out of it

Comment: What php version you have, check phpinfo() if curl is enabled. Check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993614/php-curl-is-enabled-but-has-no-effect

Comment: @flakerimi I'm using PHP version 7.3.19-1~deb10u1 on a Raspberry Pi VM (for convience). I have enabled cURL in php.ini according to this[link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-enable-curl-in-php/). I have restarted the server. Still have the undefined function curl_init() error

Comment: check if you enabled on loaded php.ini, might be somewhere else, on phpinfo() there is a path, use phpenmod curl on cli to enable. thats how you enable on windows

Comment: sudo apt install php7.3-curl

Comment: @flakerimi after installing the curl module i am receiving the POST headers but still no Content. I am having the same problem weather I use curl or file_get_contents() which leads me to believe there is an issue with the Arduino code. I have no idea what it could be since all it really does is spit out whatever it receives.

Comment: Change `$url` to a PHP page and just have `print_r($_POST);` that will show if PHP is sending data correctly.

Comment: Why not use GET, Also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944773/receiving-a-http-post-request-on-arduino

Comment: Thanks to everybody that helped me out on this last night, especially @flakerimi. Your help with getting curl working on my server may not have fixed my problem but it was valuable information. For the solution to my problem see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I let my brain rest for about half a day I determined the cause of my problem. It was not in the PHP at all. It was being caused by this IF block in the Arduino code

```
if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
    // send a standard http response header
    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    //client.println("Refresh: 5");
    client.println();
    /*client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
    client.println("<html>");
    // output the value of each analog input pin
    for (int analogChannel = 0; analogChannel < 6; analogChannel++) {
        int sensorReading = analogRead(analogChannel);
        client.print("analog input ");
        client.print(analogChannel);
        client.print(" is ");
        client.print(sensorReading);
        client.println("<br />");
    }
    client.println("</html>");*/
    break;
}
```

it was causing while loop that it is nested in to terminate at the blank line between the header and the content. My new working code for the Arduino is

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 3, 3);

// Initialize the Ethernet server library
// with the IP address and port you want to use
// (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetServer server(80);

String postData;

void setup() {
  // You can use Ethernet.init(pin) to configure the CS pin
  Ethernet.init(10);  // Most Arduino shields
  
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Serial.println("Ethernet WebServer Example");

  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  // Check for Ethernet hardware present
  if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
    while (true) {
      delay(1); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
    }
  }
  if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
  }

  // start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}


void loop() {
  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("new client");
    
    while (client.connected()) {
      while (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        postData = postData + c;
        // send a standard http response header
        client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
        client.println("Connection: close");
        client.println();
      }
      client.stop();
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);
    
    Serial.println("\r\nclient disconnected");
    Serial.println(postData);
    Serial.println(postData.substring(postData.indexOf("status=")+7, postData.indexOf("status=")+8 ));
  }
}
```