# cURL to Arduino translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, curl, arduino

I want to send a PUT request to a rails server from Arduino.

this works in curl:

```
curl -X PUT -d "barrel[gallons]=99" 192.168.0.7:3000/barrels/1
```

The server gets the call and the gallons attribute is updated.

I don't know how to format this message in Arduino.

```
String request = "PUT /barrels/1.json?barrel[gallons]=99 HTTP/1.0";
send_request(request);
Adafruit_CC3000_Client client = cc3000.connectTCP(ip, port);
// Send request
if (client.connected()) {
  client.println(request);     
  Serial.println("Connected & Data sent");
}
```

It does successfully connect to the client but the message has no effect. How should I format the request?

Answer (score 0):

If it works with curl you want the Arduino to generate exactly the same message. The issue is of course how to find out how it should look like. In such cases I usually use a debug proxy to intercept the message. The most convenient debug proxy I know of is [Fiddler2.](http://fiddler2.com/home) However in your simple case a tool like [netcat](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/299815-ncat-the-network-swiss-army-knife-) or [ncat](http://nmap.org/ncat/guide/index.html) is sufficient. Another route would be to sniff the connection with [wireshark.](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Once you can see the traffic it is usually very simple to fix all this kind of issues.

Comment: You may also want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3677400/2036917 Just change post to put.

Answer (score 0):

Note your `PUT` request in cURL will become a TCP message like following:

```
PUT /barrels/1 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.21.7 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.21.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
Host: 192.168.0.7:3000
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

barrel[gallons]=99
```

Using `Adafruit_CC3000_Client`, you are using a TCP client, and not a HTTP client.

Also

```
/barrels/1.json?barrel[gallons]=99
```

is more like a `GET` then a `PUT` request. I indeed would use a GET request because this way I wouldn't be forced to supply a message body. So, I would try:

```
String request = "GET /barrels/1?barrel[gallons]=99 HTTP/1.1";
//send_request(request); //Why here?
Adafruit_CC3000_Client client = cc3000.connectTCP(ip, port);
// Send request
if (client.connected()) {
  client.println(request);
  client.println(); //Empty line to terminate header required.
  Serial.println("Connected & Data sent");
}
```