# How to create IoT devices using UltraLight 2.0?

Tags: docker, iot, fiware, fiware-orion

I'm doing this [tutorial](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.IoT-Agent) to use Orion Context Broker in an IoT system. However, he does not explain how he created the sensors. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A previous FIWARE [tutorial](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.IoT-Sensors) explains how measures and commands can be sent from/to an IoT device over HTTP using the Ultralight payload.  The basic Ultralight requests for various transports (HTTP, MQTT etc.) can be found [here](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.NGSI-v2/blob/master/context-provider/models/measure/ultralight.js) - this is how the existing dummy devices work.

You can simulate a dummy IoT device measurement using any HTTP request. For example you can pretend to be a **Temperature Sensor** device `temperature001` using Ultralight over HTTP by making the following request

```bash
curl -L -X POST 'http://localhost:7896/iot/d?k=4jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov&i=temperature001' \
    -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
    --data-raw 't|3'
```

Where:

- `http://localhost:7896` is the SouthPort of your IoT Agent (in this case the [IoT Agent for Ultralight](https://fiware-iotagent-ul.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- `i` (device ID): Device ID (unique for the API Key).
- `k` (API Key): API Key for the service the device is registered on.
- `t` (timestamp): Timestamp of the measure. Will override the automatic IoT Agent timestamp (optional).

Obviously for a real device you would need to do the same thing using a device which has an available HTTP library - for example an Arduino, as discussed in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677400/making-a-http-post-request-using-arduino)

The full details of the Ultralight protocol can be found within the [documentation](https://fiware-iotagent-ul.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usermanual.html)